# jQuery: Call custom function after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I would like to call a custom function after a click event. 
This is the script I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btncheck').click(checkAvailability);
});

function checkAvailability() {
//code...
}
```

When I click on the button **#btncheck** the click event does not call the function **checkAvailability()**.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: does your  `#btncheck` exist in DOM model when `ready` is executed?

Comment: it works for me... open the console and check what errors you have

Comment: Your code working in jsfiddle if id of button exist please check http://jsfiddle.net/q4p5r/458/

Comment: Maybe you can post your HTML code (just the part having the button)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may use `delegate` function to bind the click event the the dom:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).delegate("#btncheck", "click", function(){
         checkAvailability();
    });
});
```

Comment: `delegate` was obsoleted in jQuery 1.7, and there's nothing in the question to explain why his existing code doesn't work anyway.